How to reduce normal vector points of a Point cloud data?
eimerI have a curved object as a point cloud and using pcl, i first downsampled it using voxelgrid and then cluster extracted my object of interest and then used normal estimation to find normal vectors.
If my task is to find the normals equidistant from each other of a distance of 10mm, how would i go about it? Basically i need to reduce the number of normal vectors (Downsampled data size is 6000+ and so is the normal vector data size the same). i tried changing the leaf size of voxelgrid but then it doesnt look right.
    pcl::NormalEstimation<pcl::PointXYZ, pcl::Normal> ne;
    ne.setInputCloud(cloud_cluster);
    pcl::search::KdTree<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr tree(new pcl::search::KdTree<pcl::PointXYZ());
    ne.setSearchMethod(tree);
    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::Normal>::Ptr cloud_normals(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::Normal>);
    ne.setRadiusSearch(10); // Use K search
    ne.compute(*cloud_normals);


    // Negate the normals to face into the plane / to face in the direction of the camera (As per requirement)
    for (size_t i = 0; i < cloud_normals->size(); ++i)
    {
        cloud_normals->points[i].normal_x *= -1;
        cloud_normals->points[i].normal_y *= -1;
        cloud_normals->points[i].normal_z *= -1;
    }


how large is the leafsize when downsampling? I think if you increase the leafsize you also have to increase the search radius. And please have a look at the documentation and compare setKSearch() and setRadiusSearch().
